# android : touch point in imageview is marked away from actual point by about 30px always

Tags: android

Am trying out an Android App, where am marking the points where the user does a long press.
For a touch-sensitive image view, I used the most of the code from here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html
along with some suggestions from various posts in stackoverflow.
This is the code for the touch image view :

```
public class SimpleImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener,OnGestureListener {
   public HashMap<meeCoordinates, Integer> plotPointsMap = new HashMap<meeCoordinates, Integer>();
   private float mPosX = 0f;
   private float mPosY = 0f;
   private boolean didLongPress = false;
   private float mLastTouchX;
   private float mLastTouchY;
   private float magicX;
   private float magicY;
   private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

   Context context;
   Canvas canvas;
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

   int deviceWidth, deviceHeight;
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    String savedItemClicked;

    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    public SimpleTouchImageView(Context ctx) {
        // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
        this(ctx, null, 0);
         this.context = ctx;
   }

   public SimpleTouchImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
       this(ctx, attrs, 0);
       this.context = ctx;
   }

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

   public SimpleTouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            // Create our ScaleGestureDetector
            if (!this.isInEditMode()) {
                  mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,new     ScaleListener());
            }
            gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(context, this);
   }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (mScaleDetector != null) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            final int action = ev.getAction();

            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                    final float x = ev.getX();
                    final float y = ev.getY();
                    // Set them to the X, Y at the beginning of the touch event
                    mLastTouchX = x;
                    mLastTouchY = y;
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                    // _handler.postDelayed(_longPressed, LONG_PRESS_TIME);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    // _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);
                    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
                    if (mScaleDetector != null) {
                         if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                            // Calculate the distance moved
                            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
                            // Move the object
                            mPosX += dx;
                            mPosY += dy;
                            // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                            mLastTouchX = x;
                            mLastTouchY = y;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                  }
                  mLastTouchX = x;
                  mLastTouchY = y;
                  break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                 // _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);
             mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
             // Calculate the Actual X & Y
             Drawable drawable = this.getDrawable();
             Rect imageBounds = drawable.getBounds();
             int intrinsicHeight = this.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
             int intrinsicWidth = this.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();

             int imageOffsetX = (int) (ev.getX() - imageBounds.left);
             int imageOffsetY = (int) (ev.getY() - imageBounds.top);

             float[] f = newfloat[9];
             this.getImageMatrix().getValues(f);

            final float scaleX = f[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
            final float scaleY = f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

            final int actualWd = Math.round(intrinsicWidth * mScaleFactor);
            final int actualHt = Math.round(intrinsicHeight * mScaleFactor);

            // CALCULATE THE X,Y COORDINATES CORRESPONDING TO THE POINT OF TOUCH
            // IN THE ACTUAL IMAGE,
            magicX = ((ev.getX() + (-1 * mPosX)) / mScaleFactor);
            magicY = ((ev.getY() + (-1 * mPosY)) / mScaleFactor);

             mLastTouchX = ev.getX();
             mLastTouchY = ev.getY();

             if (didLongPress == true) {
                  // STORE THE Point where user did long press IN AN ARRAY
                  plotPointsMap.put ( coordinates, marker );
                  invalidate();
                  didLongPress = false;
              }
              break;
        }


       case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {

            // _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL");
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break; 
       }


      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            // _handler.removeCallbacks(_longPressed);
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP");
            break;
      }
   }
   // return true;
     return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(ev);
 }



  /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
           float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
         return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }

   /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
          float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
          float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
            point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }


   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.draw(canvas);
   }


   @Override
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
       Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
       DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
       wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
       deviceWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
       deviceHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
       canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), backgroundPaint);

       if (this.getDrawable() != null) {
           canvas.save();
           canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, pivotPointX,pivotPointY);
          canvas.drawBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable()).getBitmap(), matrix,null);
          // ---add the marker---
          if ((plotPointsMap != null) && (plotPointsMap.size() > 0)) {
             for (int index = 0; index < plotPointsMap.size(); index++) {
                  Set<MyCoordinates> setCoordinates = plotPointsMap.keySet();
                  if ((setCoordinates != null) && (setCoordinates.size() > 0)) {
                          Iterator<MyCoordinates> setIterator =setCoordinates.iterator();

                          if (setIterator != null) {
                             while (setIterator.hasNext()) {
                                 MyCoordinates coordinates =  setIterator.next();
                                 int resource =                                                                plotPointsMap.get(coordinates).intValue();
                                 int resourceId = R.drawable.location_marker;
                                 Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId);
                                 float xCoordinate =  coordinates.getCoordinateX();
                                 float yCoordinate =  coordinates.getCoordinateY();
                                 canvas.drawBitmap(marker, xCoordinate * mScaleFactor, yCoordinate * mScaleFactor, null);
                             }
                          }
                        }
                  }
                } 
               canvas.restore();
            }
      }



      @Override
      public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
             // Constrain to given size but keep aspect ratio
             int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
             int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
             mLastTouchX = mPosX = 0;
             mLastTouchY = mPosY = 0;

              mScaleFactor = Math.min((float) getLayoutParams().width/ width, (float) getLayoutParams().height/ height);
             pivotPointX = ((float) getLayoutParams().width - (int) (width * mScaleFactor)) / 2;
             pivotPointY = ((float) getLayoutParams().height - (int) (height * mScaleFactor)) / 2;
             super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
      }

      float pivotPointX = 0f;
      float pivotPointY = 0f;
      ...
      ...
   }
```

**The Issue**
Let's keep aside scaling for now. Say, the image is loaded in its actual size. The point where the user touches is recorded correctly. Say, if the user touches at (120, 50) with x=120 and y=50, then it detects correctly as (120, 50). Am storing the points in an array and re-drawing a marker at each of the points in

```
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
```

The problem is that when the marker is drawn at the point (am printing it within onDraw(canvas)), the marker is drawn about 30px away from the actual point. i.e. if actual (x,y) is (120,50), then the marker image is drawn at about (150,80). Always there is this 30px difference. Why is this? Am breaking my head on this since the last two weeks in vain. Can someone please help?

here is an image showing the touch point in blue (over the letter 'S' in 'U.S.'), and you can see that the black marker is being drawn off the touch point :

[image]

**EDIT**
When I pan the image, inverse.mapPoints() doesn't account for the offset of the image away from the screen.
For example, here is the image when the App begins, this is the image loaded

[image]

and when the user pans, the image might go to the left of the screen-edge as below:

[image]

In such a case, inverse.mapPoints() only returns the value from the edge of the screen, but I want the value from the edge of the original image. How do I do it?
I tried googl'ing and tried few things given in stackoverflow (like getTop(), and getLocationOnscreen()) but in vain.

can you help?

Answer (score 1):

## 1 use getImageMatrix()

## 2 invert it - invert()

## 3 use inverted.mapPoints()

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine, but am running into another problem now, which I have added to the question itself. When I pan the image, the value given by inverted.mapPoints() doesn't account for, say, if the image is offset to the left of the screen as shown in the image above. How do I get the offset?

Comment: in onDraw use getImageMatrix() instead of matrix = new Matrix()