# How to create multiple sections of textviews using multiple touch?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on this project where I have requirement like follows,

[image]

As you can see in this image I have views with few `textViews` or `imageViews`.
User can move any `view` horizontally only, This is I am able to do and its working fine.

But I have a second scenario with multiple finger touch like this,

[image]

In this scenario user can move two views using multiple finger max. 2, This I am not able to do.

I have tried with finding the multiple pointer index in touch listener but I am not able to make it work properly.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Follow this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html

Comment: This question is too broad and would require significant effort to be answered. Asking for a tutorial is also not in the scope of SO.

Comment: For this,You need to understand how touch event work in Android.It is a very broad topic.You need to have proper understanding of `MotionEvent` ,how and when they are triggered.I would recommend you to listen to this talk from Dave Smith on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI&t=3650s

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Not Much of a kotlin fan yet , but i did implemented this kind of task a while ago.

I created a view on which if you multi touch it will give you exact *android.graphics.PointF* object for the finger , then you can easily compare by getting position other views on top of my view to check if finger is pressing/dragging that particular view.View is hosted on [Github](https://gist.github.com/ZulqurnainSDSOL/dd59b3d6c21648deaa8a3b3a14e8e10c).

And to check if finger point is overlapping other view , check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19949906/8399299).

**Note:** this answer is just to kick start your process of solving the problem , as question itself is too broad to answer completely

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out. I understand that the question is too broad, So I have started working on my own to achieve this functionality. I do have found some success a while back and I have uploaded the demo project on GitHub, here's the link, [github.com/nightfox8/SwipeDemo](http://github.com/nightfox8/SwipeDemo) To all those who might need this kind of solution in future, Thanks